# How can I references too many projects (folders) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When I used Visual Studio, I had two files format solution (.sln) and project (.csproj).

I want to know in Visual Code

How can I have solution (Root folder) and many projects (sub folders) with dependencies to itself ?

How can I set folders dependencies ?

please guide me or introduce a source that How can I add many related project with their dependencies in Visual Code.